# Multiple Counts On Same Row With Conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to calculate a summarised view of the data in my table, at the moment the query works but it isn't very efficient seeing as my table will eventually hold 10,000 + contracts.  I also need to filter each by the same date, I realise I could do this in the where statement for each count but this isn't very efficient.

Also the final calculation at the end would be much easier if I could operate on fields rather than selects.

```
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractWon = 1) Won,
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractPassedToCS = 1) PassedtoCS,
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractPassedToCS = 0) as OutstandingWithSales,
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractIssued = 1) as ContractsIssued,
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractReturned = 1) as ContractsReturned,
(CONVERT(decimal, (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractReturned = 1)) /         CONVERT(decimal, (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Contracts WHERE contractIssued = 1))) * 100 as '% Outstanding'
```

I understand there is probably some joining needed but I'm a little confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(contractWon) AS Won,
    SUM(contractPassedToCS ) AS PassedtoCS,
    SUM(1-contractPassedToCS) AS OutstandingWithSales,
    SUM(contractIssued) AS contractIssued ,
    SUM(contractReturned) AS contractReturned,
    100.0 * SUM(contractReturned) / SUM(contractIssued) AS '% Outstanding'
FROM
    Mytable
```

Alternate formulations for "bit" datatypes which can not be aggregated. If the columns are int, say, then the above query works

```
    --Either CAST first to a type that aggregates...
    SUM(CAST(contractWon AS int)) AS Won,

    -- .. or rely on COUNT ignores NULL values
    COUNT(CASE contractWon WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Won,
```

Comment: Wrap each of those in a SUM() and I'll +1 it :-)

Comment: I will +1 one if you comment on your (albeit fair) assumption that the columns are booleans represented by 1/0, (which the OP did not state).

Comment: Apologies, they were all indeed booleans.